# How to pass function pointer to member function c++?

Tags: c++, oop, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

So this is like my 2nd question regarding the topic but this time I want to know what if i pass a function which is of int type.Like here I want to store output of fun1 in variable "int my" in main function. How should i write the wrapper function for this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
public:
    int fun1(int m) 
    { 
        return 2*m;
    }

    int wrapper(int (student::*fun)(int k))
    {
        (this->*fun)(int k)
    }
};

int main()
{   
    student s;
    int l=5;
    int my=s.wrapper(&student::fun1(l));
    cout << m << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's questionable what you want to achieve with that wrapper function at all.

Comment: Completely wrong. `(this->*fun)(int k)` is not valid C++, @user0042.

Comment: @user0042 getting error :(

Comment: @codie consider reading the error message. It usually tells you what is wrong.

Comment: @user0042 i want to pass fun1 into wrapper and then want to return value 2*m in variable my.

Comment: `(this->*fun)(int k)` is not valid C++. This is a function call, no different than any other function call, except that the function is called via a method pointer. Function calls have values as parameters. To pass the value 2, for example, to a function that takes an `int` parameter, you just specify the value 2. And not `int 2`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  i wrote k instead of int k and got error that k was not declared in this scope

Comment: also got error cannot call member function ‘int student::fun1(int)’ without object

Comment: Well, you did not declare `k` in that scope. I see no declaration of `k` in there, so why are you surprised that your compiler has a problem with that?

Comment: Consider using [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) with [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapper caller needs two parameters:
One for the function to call, and one for the 
parameter to call it with

```
int wrapper(int (student::*fun)(int), int k)
{
    return (this->*fun)(k);
}
```

Call it like:

```
int my = s.wrapper(&student::fun1, 1);
cout << my << endl;
```

See it here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd93094c38bfa591

Answer (score 1):

Why bother to create your own wrapper when there is [`mem_fn()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) provided in the standard library:

```
int my = mem_fn(&student::fun1)(&s,l);
cout<<my<<endl;
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/CJsFDt)